# Record/Capture desktop for specific time period

Tags: video, recording

I use `gtk-recordmydesktop` and/or `recordmydesktop` to record my desktop and create screen-casts.

I need to record my desktop for a given period of time, let's say 1 hour, so that I can record stuff while I am gone. How should I go about doing it? I could not find any argument in `recordmydesktop` to allow this. Does any other tool provide this feature?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found an answer. It was right there in the `man` page of `recordmydesktop`. In the man page, it is clearly given that `recordmydesktop` will stop recording AND **save the video**,  if it receives any of these signals: `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT`.

Now, by default `kill` command sends the `SIGTERM` signal. Hence, if we know the `pid` of the running `recormydesktop` process, we can simply kill the process gracefully, ensuring that the video is also saved.

Here is one way to do this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
recordmydesktop --on-the-fly-encoding &
sleep 2700        #keep recording for 45 minutes
kill `echo $!`
```

Comment: Or instead of `kill 'echo $!'` just use `pkill recordmydesktop`

Comment: Why do you use `echo $!` instead of just `kill $!` directly?

Comment: @thrig Yes.... `echo $!` doesn't make much sense... don't remember why I did that... it's been 2 years since I answered that.... `kill $!` should be perfectly fine....